# How to catch event of hyperlink in controller in extjs4?

Tags: hyperlink, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, extjs2

I am working in extjs4 MVC.I am getting stuck at a point where **I have to catch event click of hyperlink in extjs4**.I want to catch that event in controllers 'control' method.I tried a lot but not get solved please some one give some suggestion to how to solve this problem.

1)Here is my some view code :--

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.linkView', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias:'widget.Link',
    title:'hyper link',
    items:[
    {
        xtype: 'box',
        autoEl: {tag: 'a', href: '#', html: 'Click on this button',id:'link'}
    }]
});// End of login class
```

2)Here is my controller code: ---

```
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     views: ['user.linkView'],

     init: function() {
         this.control({
             'Link box[tag: a]':
                 click:this.linkClicked
         });
     },
     linkClicked:function()
     {
         console.log("clicked on link");
     }
});
```

I tried a lot on it.but not get solved this problem.How can I solve this this please give some suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Ext.define('AM.view.user.linkView', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias:'widget.Link',
    name:'linkPanel',
    title:'hyper link',
    items:[
    {
        xtype: 'box',
        autoEl: {tag: 'a', href: '#', html: 'Click on this button',id:'link'}
    }]
});// End of login class
```

Use below code in controller

```js
var controller = this;
controller.control({
   'linkPanel': {
      afterrender: function() {
           Ext.get('link').on('click', function() {
                controller.linkClicked();
           });
      }
   }
});
```

This will work !!!!

Thanks